# Custom callback with parameter to be called by array_filter()

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering

I got this multiple array named `$files[]`, which consists of keys and values as below:

```
[
    [
        'name' => 'index1.php',
        'path' => 'http://localhost/php/gettingstarted/',
        'number' => 1,
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'index10.php',
        'path' => 'http://localhost/php/gettingstarted/',
        'number' => 2,
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'index11.php',
        'path' => 'http://localhost/php/gettingstarted/',
        'number' => 3,
    ],
]
```

I use this code to create a new array consist of 'name' keys only. But it failed

```
array_filter($files, "is_inarr_key('name')");

function is_inarr_key($array, $key)
{
    //TODO : remove every array except those who got the same $key
}
```

and I get this error:

> array_filter() [function.array-filter]: The second argument, 'is_inarr_key('name')', should be a valid callback in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\gettingstarted\index.php on line 15

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to make the call-back function on `array_filter` receive parameter?
2. What is the general rule of thumb on how to use callback in any PHP built-in function?

Comment: This question is Unclear about the actual required filtering logic.  Can we have a [mcve] please?  Are you retaining rows which have a key called `name` or are you filtering rows which contain a specific value in the `name` column or are you wanting to isolate the values in the `name` column as a new array? That `I use this code to create a new array consist of 'name' keys only.` sentence makes me believe it is the third one.  In which case, you don't need `array_filter()`, you want `array_column()`. This question may be an XY Problem.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can create a closure on PHP ≥5.3.

```
array_filter($files, function($array) use ($key) {
  return is_inarr_key($array, $key); 
} );
```

---

If you are stuck with PHP <5.3, …

You can make `$key` a global variable.

```
function is_inarr_with_global_key($array) {
   global $key;
   ....
}
```

You can create a class

```
class KeyFilter {
  function KeyFilter($key) { $this->key = $key; }
  function is_inarr_key($array) { ... }
}
...
array_filter($files, array(new KeyFilter('name'), 'is_inarr_key'));
```

You can create 3 different functions

```
array_filter($files, 'is_inarr_name');
array_filter($files, 'is_inarr_path');
array_filter($files, 'is_inarr_number');
```

You can write your own `array_filter`

```
function my_array_filter($files, $key) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: i haven't try it. but this solution's brilyan. if i convert my code work with closure or class, i will able to work with more keys AND create ONLY one fun ction : is_inarr_key()

Comment: +1, but if it were my answer I would list the closure-based solution first and recommend it over the alternatives. It's the simplest and shortest of the possibilities by far.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the [`array_walk`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) function as:

```
$arr = array(
        array("name" => "Jack", "id" => 1),
        array("name" => "Rose", "id" => 2),
    );

$result = array(); // initialize result array.
array_walk($arr, "filter"); // iterate over the array calling filter fun for each value.
// $result will now have elements "Jack" and "Rose"

function filter($a) {

    global $result; // to access the global result array.

    $result[] = $a['name']; // for each array passed, save the value for the key 'name' in the result array.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am unaware if you can supply the callback function with parameters, but as a suggestion, you could define a callback function for `array_filter`

```
array_filter($files, "is_inarr_key");
```

And to get the `name` of the array, just loop over the `$file[]` and retrieve the `name.` Then, having the `name` you can go on with your logic.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

You can use create_function() in 5.2.x

```
$y = 5;
$func = 'return $x > ' . $y . ';';
$f = create_function('$x', $func);
$numbers = range(0, 10);
$result = array_filter($numbers, $f);
print_r($result);
```

which outputs

> Array
>   (
>       [6] => 6
>       [7] => 7
>       [8] => 8
>       [9] => 9
>       [10] => 10
>   )

Answer (score 1):

thanks KennyTM for [keyfilter class great tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2529784/1055281).
For those who care and don't know how to do it, this a working detailed example.
I slightly improved  using a regexp pattern.

$files[]= {code above};

```
class KeyFilter {
    function KeyFilter($attr,$pattern)
    {
        $this->attr=$attr;
        $this->pattern=$pattern;
    }
    function is_inarr_key($t)
    {
        return preg_match($this->pattern,$t[$this->attr]);;
    }
}


$t=array_filter($items, array(new KeyFilter("path","~\d{2}\.php~i"), 'is_inarr_key'));
print_r($t);
print_r($o->key);
```

output:

```
[1] => Array
(
    [name] => index**10**.php
    [path] => http://localhost/php/gettingstarted/
    [number] => 2
)

[2] => Array
(
    [name] => index**11**.php
    [path] => http://localhost/php/gettingstarted/
    [number] => 3
)
```