# PHP array_filter, how to get the key in callback?

Tags: php, arrays, callback, array-filter

> array_filter — Filters elements of an array using a callback function
>
> `array array_filter ( array $input [, callback $callback ] )`

Can callback get the key of the current array value and how?

Answer (score 18):

From the documentation:
PHP 5.6.0   Added optional flag parameter and constants `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` and `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 9):

In a previous comment you outlined you're actually looking for something like this:

```
foreach ($t as $k => $v)
    if (!array_key_exists($k, $valid))
        unset($t[$k])
```

So actually to remove all values from array `$t` that do not have a key in array `$valid`.

The PHP function for that is called [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key). The intersection is equal to the filtered result:

```
$filtered = array_intersect_key($t, $valid);
```

Answer (score 5):

By using the `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH` constant, you can get both value and key :

```
array_filter($arrFoo, function ($value, $key) { return 'name' === $key && $value > 1 }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH)
```

By using the `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` constant, you can get key alone :

```
array_filter($arrFoo, function ($key) { return 'name' === $key }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY)
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to let the callback of [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) access the element's key, nor is there a similar function that does what you want.

However, you can write your own function for this, like the one below:

```
function arrayfilter(array $array, callable $callback = null) {
    if ($callback == null) {
        $callback = function($key, $val) {
            return (bool) $val;
        };
    }
    $return = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        if ($callback($key, $val)) {
            $return[$key] = $val;
        }
    }
    return $return;
}

$test_array = array('foo', 'a' => 'the a', 'b' => 'the b', 11 => 1101, '', null, false, 0);

$array = arrayfilter($test_array, function($key, $val) {
   return is_string($key);
});
print_r($array);
/*
Array
(
    [a] => the a
    [b] => the b
)
*/

$array = arrayfilter($test_array);
print_r($array);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [a] => the a
    [b] => the b
    [11] => 1101
)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the array_walk function as discussed here (3rd answer down): [is it possible if callback in array_filter receive parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529728/is-it-possible-if-callback-in-array-filter-receive-parameter)

Comment: Too tricky, and i'm working with indexed arrays not associative ones. In that solution keys are hardcoded.

Comment: Perhaps a more standard `code`foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {} implementation would serve your needs.

Comment: I need to filter the input array: if key exists in another array then return the element. I found `array_filter` the candidate but i can't get the key of the current array value in callback.

Comment: That is: `foreach ($t as $k => $v) if (!array_key_exists($k, $valid)) unset($t[$k])` but looks horrible to me...

Comment: That's pretty much how I'd go about implementing what you've described so far.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't like the other options suggested here, if anyone else is looking for this feature, here is a quick implementation:

```
function array_filter_keys($a, $c){
    $i=array_filter(array_keys($a), $c);
    return array_intersect_key($a, array_flip($i));
}
```

The result of this function is exactly what it sounds like, it will return an array filtered by a callback function that receives the keys rather than the values.

EDIT:
This is more of a disclaimer, after reading some of the other comments I realize that the OP is actually just looking for `array_intersect` as hakre pointed out. I will leave this answer here though since the OPs question does not clearly state that need and this page shows up in google for array_filter_keys